# Meteor client can't import collection defined in server. Trying to import collection documents

Tags: meteor, collections, import, publish-subscribe

On the client, I am trying to console.log documents from a collection defined in the server.

I have server file which defines and publishes a collection to the client.

### Server file: server/main.js

```
const Translations = new Mongo.Collection('translations');

Meteor.startup(function () {
    Meteor.publish('translationsChannel', function () {
     return Translations.find();
    });
});

module.exports = Translations;
```

### Client file: client/main.js

I then import the Translations collection and subscribe to 'translationsChannel' in the client.

```
import Translations     from '../../server/main.js';
const translationsSub = Meteor.subscribe("translationsChannel");

if (translationsSub.ready()) {
  console.log('Translations: ', Translations.find().fetch());
}
```

### Problem: client can't import Translations successfully

Why can't I import the Translations collection to the client?

Answer (score 2):

I identified the problem.

**You can't define collections in the server and export them to the client**. To fix the problem:

- I made an imports/collections.js file that defined the Translation collection and exports it.

  ```
  const Translations = new Mongo.Collection('translations');

  Translations.schema = new SimpleSchema({
    userId: {type: String},
    fromLanguage: {type: String},
    fromText: {type: String},
    toLanguage: {type: String},
    toText: {type: String},
  });

  module.exports = Translations;
  ```
- I then import Translation in my server/main.js file

  ```
  import Translations from '../imports/collections.js'

  Meteor.startup(function () {
    Meteor.publish('translationsChannel', function () {
     return Translations.find();
    });
  })
  ```
- I then import Translation in my client/main.js file

  ```
   import Translations from '../imports/collections.js';
   const translationsSub = Meteor.subscribe("translationsChannel");

   if (translationsSub.ready()) {
     console.log('Translations: ', Translations.find().fetch());
   }
  ```
- The trick is that you need a common directory half way between the server and the client. You can import collections from the 'middle-common' folder into both the server and the client

Comment: You could just put these in a folder called 'common' - this is implicitly imported by Meteor to both client and server. This is part of the old way that still works quite well :)